# Extending Taylor's theorem from one to several variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

In my calculus class we are dealing with Taylor´s theorem in several variables. When we were looking at the function $f(x,y)=\sin(xy)$ my teacher said that instead of applying the theorem in several variables we can just apply Taylor´s theorem in one variable and then replace the variable by $xy$:

$$\sin(t)=t-{t^3\over 3!}+{t^5\over 5!}+ R_5(t)$$ which yields: $$\sin(xy)=xy-{(xy)^3\over 3!}+{(xy)^5\over 5!}+ R_5(xy)$$

My question is: when can we do this kind of replacement? What conditions does the function must satisfy? Or we just do it whenever we can? I would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Your formula for sine is true for any number $t$. And $xy$ is a number, after all. (Assuming $x$ and $y$ are numbers.)

Comment: As said in comments and answers, this should not be called an extension of Taylor series from one to several variables. In what you post, you replace $t$ by $2t$ or by $x y z$.

Answer (score 2):

The justification is very simple and once you understand it you'll see how to use it elsewhere. So, given any values for $x$ and $y$, the value of $xy$ is just some number, call it $t$. Now, you are trying to compute $\sin (xy)$ which is just $\sin t$, so you can use Taylor's expansion for $\sin$ and compute $\sin (t)$ using it. Ahhhh, but $t=xy$ so you find that when you compute $\sin (t)$ you are just replacing $t$ by $xy$.

This will work in general when the function of several variables can be presented as the composition of a function of one variable with another function of several variables. In cases such as $x\sin (y)$ this approach will not work.

Comment: it is perhaps interesting to add that the derivation of the multivariate Taylor series naturally flows from the single variate Taylor result and the chain rule. So, while this case is special, in general it is not so far removed from the nastier looking cases.